# How to get CMake to build a Fortran program with MPI support?

Tags: cmake, fortran, mpi

I was trying to parallelize a Fortran program using MPI.  I use CMake to do the build of my program.  It was difficult to find support on getting CMake to create a working makefile for Fortran with MPI support on google, but from what I could gather, I added the following commands to my CMakeLists.txt script:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_definitions(${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})
include_directories(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${MPI_FortranLIBRARY_DIRS})
```

This will locate MPI on my system and then set the variables found in the following three commands.  In my linking line, I added the MPI libraries variable to the list of the other libraries that my program needed to build.

```
target_link_libraries(${exe_name} otherlibs ${MPI_FortranLIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Doing `cmake` and then `make` worked to build the program and the program ran; however, when I tried to add more to the source which required me to include the `mpif.h` include file, my compilation failed due to not being able to find this header file.  I also could not `use mpi` because the compiler cannot find the `mpi.mod` file in the path.

Answer (score 2):

I inserted "message" commands into my CMakeLists.txt file and printed out the values of the variables that I was using for including and linking.  It turns out that the variables, `MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `MPI_FortranLIBRARY_DIRS` weren't set to anything.  A check of the module that CMake is actually using to set these variables (FindMPI.cmake) showed these variables to be non-existent.  I changed my CMakeLists.txt file to use the correct variables:

```
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_definitions(${MPI_Fortran_COMPILE_FLAGS})
include_directories(${MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH})
link_directories(${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${exe_name} otherlibs ${MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES})
```

Now when I execute `make`, the compiler could find both `mpif.h` as well as `mpi.mod`.

UPDATE:

I want to mention that this solution worked for cmake version 2.8.10.1.  When I moved my CMakeLists.txt scripts to a different machine that has cmake version 2.8.4, I get the same error about `mpi.mod` missing during the link stage.  I checked the FindMPI.cmake module and, sure enough, there are no variables that specify the language (i.e. there is no `MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES` variable, just a `MPI_LIBRARIES` variable, and this variable is not getting set to the correct location of the mpi library on that system.  So this solution will be dependent on cmake version.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not using the mpi compiler. That is fine, but you have to add a lot of flags then. There is not really an mpi compiler but a wrapper that sets the flags to be able to use mpi. With cmake I was able to do this by defining the fortran compiler I was going to use BEFORE the call to cmake. It's not a nice solution since you loose portability, but it works. I'm trying to find a better solution and define inside cmake what compiler to use, but have not been able to do so. In other words, this works for me:

```
    FC=mpif90 cmake ../.
    make
```

I was having the same problem as you. Hope this solves the issue. If anybody finds how to define the fortran compiler INSIDE cmake please post it!

Answer (score 0):

as you've  already noticed, you misspelled the name of two variables, namely `MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES` and `MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES`

It is useful also to add:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
```

at the very beginning of your CMake to be sure that these variables will be defined.